# Import Bootstrap theme into Odoo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, import, odoo

Good Day, I would like to learn how to import custom Boostrap themes i own into my Odoo website, packaging them as theme_modules. 
In particular, I need to enlarge my building block library with more snippets.

So I created a new empty theme_module following the [documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/themes.html) then I started copy paste code blocks from a free test Bootrap theme i have (you can find and download it [here](http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/worthy) but i'm stuck.
Could you please help me showing me how to properly import them or at least leading me to a good tutorial/documentation (free)

I also followed a bit [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/new-bootstrap-theme-on-website-builder-58809#answer-58814) guide but it didn't help very much:

Answer (score 0):

That's a manual process which can be done in several steps, you will need some creativity to separate by really usefull and functional blocks your code.

1. Try to migrate plainly all the demo pages on your theme, creting pages on odoo.
2. Try to include your css (I recommend use less instead) but css will work.
3. Just then when 1 and 2 is working start to split them.

Advice: Buy one of the [paid themes](https://www.odoo.com/apps/themes) and read the code there it will help you with several techniques and will give you access to several cool private modules (like website_less which automagically convert your less in css just as you were writting css).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thank you! I'm trying with that. I'd buy one of the paid theme if only they would be less expensive... 200$ just to see how it works are too much.

I really would like to see a tutorial or someghing somewhere

Comment: This is the official version of the theme building documentation, but as I prefer read the code and really appreciate contribute to odoo I buy them always (read the code is better that incomplete books.)  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/themes.html